# 'Intent' does not contain a definition for 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have started programming an Xamarin Android App that changes the activity when the alarm goes off. Everywhere online everyone says to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or similar flags to call a new activity. For some reason, my Intent does not have any of those flags defined.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "THIS IS MY ALARM", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.SetClassName("AlarmReceiver", "AlarmActivated");
        i.SetFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //error
        context.StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why this flag, or other similar flags are not defined? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xamarin "C# normalizes" the Android/Java methods/properties and at times moves enums/flags into their own "sub" enums, `FLAG_ACTIVITY{_XXX}` becomes an `ActivityFlags` enum.

So `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` becomes `ActivityFlags.NewTask`

Answer (score 0):

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

In my case **addFlags** was helped instead of **setFlags**